# How to get parent data inside an Handlebars Helper scope?

Tags: handlebars.js, parent

I'm trying to generate an option set where I can select the selected option but I'm not able to access to `timeSpent` when I nest the Helpers like in the examples above:

This is how I send data to my handlebars template:

```
{
    feed : {
        foodMinutes : 90,
        timeSpent : 72
    }
}
```

This is where I generate my select option, I thought there was a way like `../timeSpent` to get parent data but it doesn't work:

```
<select>
    {{#count feed.foodMinutes 1 0}}
    {{#equal ../timeSpent this}}
    <option value="{{this}}" selected>{{this}} minuti</option>
    {{else}}
    <option value="{{this}}">{{this}} minuti</option>
    {{/equal}}
    {{/count}}
</select>
```

These are my helpers:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("count", function(count, step, start, block) {
    var accum, steps, startFrom;
    accum = "";
    steps = step || 1;
    startFrom = start || 0;

    for(var i = startFrom; i < count; i += steps) {
        accum += block.fn(i);
    }
    return accum;
});

Handlebars.registerHelper("equal", function(lvalue, rvalue, options) {
    if (arguments.length < 3) {
        throw new Error("Handlebars Helper equal needs 2 parameters");
    }
    if (lvalue != rvalue) {
        return options.inverse(this);
    } else {
        return options.fn(this);
    }
});
```

So how can I get the parent data inside an Handlebars Helper scope?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simple, I've used `../feed.timeSpent` instead of `../timeSpent`:

```
<select>
    {{#count feed.foodMinutes 1 0}}
    {{#equal ../feed.timeSpent this}}
    <option value="{{this}}" selected>{{this}} minuti</option>
    {{else}}
    <option value="{{this}}">{{this}} minuti</option>
    {{/equal}}
    {{/count}}
</select>
```